# testear componente con Cypress con vueX

Tags: vue.js, test, vuex, testing, cypress

estoy implementando un pequeño test que verifique un componente, pero este tiene dependencias de vueX, y me lanza este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El test es muy sencillo, y solo quiero que me diga si el componente se esta montando adecuadamente:

```
    import DropDownHeader from '@/pages/_root/views/DropDownHeader.vue';


describe('Lista de Unidades', () => {
  it('should visit', () => {
    cy.mount(DropDownHeader);
  });
```

});

Soy nuevo haciendo test, y no se como cargar estos datos de forma simulada.